# how to Code Sign EV certificate using electron-builder?

Tags: electron, code-signing, electron-builder

I'm using electron-builder.

I can see their documentation mention about EV Code signing.

https://www.electron.build/code-signing.html#windows

But it doesn't say in detail HOW.

In docs, it says `If you are using an EV Certificate, you need to provide win.certificateSubjectName in your electron-builder configuration.`

But what about the `CSC_LINK` and `CSC_KEY_PASSWORD` env? Are they not needed?

Using EV cert, the certificate is bound to USB dongle and I can't export it as `.pfx` or set password.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering myself.

You can omit `CSC_LINK` & `CSC_KEY_PASSWORD` since EV cert doesn't give you `.pfx` file and password.

Instead, you set `certificateSubjectName` in `electron-builder`'s configuration.

Then it will automatically find certificate installed in your machine with that subject name.

When building, an authorization client used by your cert distributer will pop up to ask token password.

Of course, you need to have USB dongle plugged in.

Comment: Hello, as you mentioned, the HOW is not there. I'm pretty sure that you followed more steps that these finals just mentioned. Could you tell where you found them?

Comment: @FerToasted I figured it out on my own. I think I explained pretty much all the steps needed here above. Tell me where you are struggling at. I'll give you more details.

Comment: Amazing, I searched for hours not knowing how to use this new EV token, this solved my issue. Im not sure why they don't explain this anywhere else. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Guest-01, thank you very much for this post. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, but I'm not sure if the fault is to the certificate in itself, PowerShell, or the Electron builder script. Does it still work for you? And if yes, where does your certificate comes from? I would be curious to see the result of the PowerShell command executed by Electron Builder in your case to be able to diagnose where the problem is coming. I explain my issue here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/7729

Comment: @Stéphane I'm not sure either but try update powershell first, if it still doesn't work then try different version of electron-builder by changing version number in package.json and npm install again. I'm on windows 10, using powershell 5, electron-builder 23 and works fine.

Comment: Thank you @Guest-01. Could you please tell me what is the output of this command for you? `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert: -CodeSigningCert | Select-Object -Property Subject,PSParentPath,Thumbprint | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`

Comment: @Stéphane I get same null values: [{"Subject":null,"PSParentPath":null,"Thumbprint":null}...etc. Other commands also outputs just like yours.

Comment: Thank you @Guest-01. So maybe I'm on the wrong track here, and the problem is actually the "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CodeSigningCert'" part. If I find how to solve this, I'll comment here in case it can be helpful for others.

Comment: Found the problem: there are two versions of Powershell on Windows: the one called "Windows Powershell" (powershell.exe), that is Powershell version 5.x and that is kept on all Windows systems for compatibility reasons, and the newer versions called "Powershell" (pwsh.exe), that is Powershell version 6.x, 7.x, ... The command called by electron-builder is "powershell.exe", and strangely enough doesn't work from the newer Powershell because of the ":" character. Launching the build/deploy script from Windows Power Shell (the 5.x version) fixed the problem.

Comment: @Guest-01 Thank you so much for your answer... you saved my day